# Как правильно тестировать запросы, требующие авторизацию, при использовании Cookie?

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

В своем проекте использую Spring 2.2.4, как вы понимаете есть методы, требующие авторизацию - в которых я получаю текущего пользователя из сессии - как это все организовать в тестах, понимаю что как то надо замокать секьюрити, но опыта в данной теме вообще никакого. Вот это метод получения текущего юзера из сессии:

```
 public User getCurrentUser() throws Exception {
 Authentication auth = 
 SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

 if (null == auth) {
   throw new NotFoundException("");
 }

 Object obj = auth.getPrincipal();
 String username = "";

 if (obj instanceof UserDetails) {
  username = ((UserDetails) obj).getUsername();
 } else {
   username = obj.toString();
 }

 User user = userRepository.findByEmail(username).get();
 return user;
```

}

как мне все это лучше организовать?

хотелось бы сделать тесты подобного вида:

```
  @Test
void findPostById() {
 PostByIdApi postByIdApi = postService.findPostById(8);
 Assertions.assertEquals(8, postByIdApi.getId());
 Assertions.assertEquals("Rerum eos quam.", postByIdApi.getTitle());
```

}